# error: ‘grub_disk_get_size’ not found

Tags: debian, dual-boot, grub

I am using dual boot with sony vaio laptop with windows 8.1 and Debian 10. After installing debian, i didnt use windows at all. today I boot into windows and when I am done,I reboot. i get the error in the question and am on grub rescue prompt. I am a noob. what to do? I tried the `ls` command to find the ext2 file format partition/disk. its (hd0,gpt8).

Comment: I tried system recovery and accidentally erased windows :P and everything with it and failed to recover windows. now just installing debian hopefully it works

Comment: gonna leave the question open incase anyone wants to answer